# kotlin findViewById returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I have the following code which after clicking on the button findViewById returns null but when I set the onclick attribute of the picture itself to change the picture there is no null exception returned.

This code returns null exception:

```
private lateinit var imageView1: ImageView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun change(view: View){
    try {
        imageView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
    }
    catch (e: Exception){
        Log.d("errors","first")
    }
}
```

---

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="430dp"
        android:layout_height="487dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lion"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-22dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-9dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="change"
        android:text="change"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="157dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="667dp" />
```

This code doesn't return null exception and the picture changes, in this code only the xml part is changed and the Kotlin part is the same as previous part:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="430dp"
        android:layout_height="487dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lion"
        android:onClick="change"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-22dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-9dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="change"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="157dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="667dp" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you do

```
imageView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

you are looking for the view within any children that the button clicked has. You need to just do

```
imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

Comment: Thank you for your working answer but why it works for the imageView and not for the button? Aren't both button and the imageView children's of the view property?

Comment: @Freelancer But the imageView is not a child of the button. The `view` in `view.findViewById` is the clicked view. I suppose `findViewById` can return itself if it has the id

Comment: Is in the second code view = the imageView and every imageView is the child of itself?

Comment: @Freelancer to quote the description of `findViewById`: "Finds the first descendant view with the given ID, the view itself if the ID matches getId(), or null if the ID is invalid (< 0) or there is no matching view in the hierarchy."

Comment: How the code
imageView1 = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)
in first code works?
This my answer right? : 'the view itself if the ID matches getId()'
The method returns the view itself if the id matches.

Comment: @Freelancer your first xml fails because you make the button clickable and do findViewById on the button. The second xml works by making the imageview itself clickable and findViewById works because it matches the clicked view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245781/discussion-between-freelancer-and-ivo-beckers).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code after modifying the `change` method

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun change(view: View){
    when(view.id){
       R.id.imageView -> (view as ImageView).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
       R.id.button -> (view as Button).text = "Clicked"
    }
}
```